Magento 2 : Can you streamline Tax Exempt rejection?
Currently the Tax Exempt application from the Admin side has no option for a streamlined rejection process, is just a Y or N switch.
Is it possible to have a rejection flow where a template goes out inviting someone to re-apply or else, all from Magento?
Rejections when a customer uploads an invalid Form are a manual process through and through, involving multiple of our teams to resolve.
What options to streamline Tax Exempt application Rejections are available?
thanks!, Andres

Can you specify more details.
